# CSS: inverted and backwards text

Tags: css

Are there any CSS gurus out there up to the challenge of representing one of Edgar Poe's cryptographic texts? It uses inverted and backwards characters, which would have driven his type composer crazy. The image file tyler.jpg appears about 3/5 of the way down the linked page: [Secret Writing 03](https://www.howtoreadpoe.com/content/k-secret_writing/sw03.htm)

Trying to find CSS examples across the 'net but not much success.

Comment: What do you mean by "inverted"?

Comment: Please see the linked image. "Inverted" means "upside down" in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms provide this pretty simply. For example

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
span::before {
  content: 'P';
}
span:nth-child(2n) {
  scale: -1;
}
span:nth-child(n+3) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, Aloha; that's a start for me, but it looks like I would need to create a separate span tag for each affected character. ? I don't see your example text, just the result. As you can tell, I am no coder. I can see the rotation effect, but how do you do an upside down AND backwards character?

Comment: @JackDeLand - Yes you need a separate element for each character. To do both upside down and backwards you apply both the rotate and the scale transforms to the same element.

Comment: Thanks again. Now all I have to do is figure out how to do this within a line of text where some but not all characters need the transform. I hope you can look at the link in the original post to see the original. This is Poe's most notorious cryptogram.

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't read the tiny type very well. Thank you Alohci. I believe I have enough to get started now.

Answer (score 0):

Provided by Mattias Sander, Improvementsoft (Sweden)

```
    span.horizontal {
        display: inline-block;
        -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
        transform: scale(-1, 1);
    }

    span.vertical {
        display: inline-block;
        -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
        -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
        transform: scale(1, -1);
    }
```